# Force terminate AutoScaling instances stuck in Pending:Wait

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have an AutoScaling group where I'm messing around with LifecycleHooks on instance start, some controlled by me and some controlled by other AWS services. I've been adding/removing LifecycleHooks and changing the size of the ASG, and instances are getting stuck in `Pending:Wait`. I assume it's because it's waiting for a signal from a LifecycleHook, but I can't get it to budge.

I tried a number of things:

**Terminate instances in EC2 console**

I terminated the instances, but ASG waits for the LifecycleHook heartbeat to timeout before actually terminating the instance from the ASG, which is probably an hour.

**Complete LifecycleHooks manually**

I tried to complete the LifecycleHooks manually, illustrated by the following pseudocode:

```
describeAutoScalingGroups -> asg {
    instances = getPending(asg.instances)
    describeLifecycleHooks -> lifecycleHooks {
        lifecycleHooks.each {
            instances.each {
                completeLifecycleAction(instance, hook)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't do the trick. I'm guessing the LifecycleHook it's waiting on was deleted from the ASG, so there's no way to manually complete the LifecycleHook.

**What next?**

Obviously, I should be more careful about deleting these resources in the right order and all that and decreasing the heartbeat will help as well, but **how can I force terminate instances from an ASG no matter what it's waiting for?**

Answer (score 13):

After terminating EC2 instance in Console, manually completing LifecycleHook worked for me:

```
aws autoscaling complete-lifecycle-action --lifecycle-hook-name $HOOK --auto-scaling-group-name $ASG --lifecycle-action-result ABANDON --instance-id $ID
```

Comment: Reference [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/completing-lifecycle-hooks.html#completing-lifecycle-hooks-aws-cli)

Comment: Heroic.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In case someone runs out the same problem, it depends of what your lifecycle hook is calling.

If it calls CodeDeploy then you can go to CodeDeploy and stop any running deployment that could be hanging or taking too much time.
You can check which event script is pending.

Answer (score -2):

Ran into this problem today, and I was able force delete using the AWS CLI.

```
aws autoscaling delete-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name <asg name> --force-delete
```

However please note that for this to work, you must use the `--force-delete` argument the first time itself, if the ASG is already in a pending delete state, this will not work.

Comment: That isn't quite the same problem. I wanted to terminate a specific instance, not the entire ASG. Unfortunately, the terminate instance API does not have a force delete option.